# Integral over a pyramid

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $K=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x+y+z\leq 1\}.$ Calculate its volume and the integral $$\int_K=\frac{d(x,y,z)}{(1+x+y+z)^3}.$$

To evaluate the volume, I defined the sets: $B_x=\{y\in \mathbb{R}\mid \exists z\in \mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)\in B\}$ and $B_{xy}=\{z\in\mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)\in B\}$ and then calculated:
$$\int_B x,y,z=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}1 \mathop{dz}\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}=\frac{1}{6}$$
But I'm not sure how to evaluate the other integral.

Comment: OH MY GOD! THE VOLUME IS 1/3 BASE * HEIGHT. BASE = 1/2 * (1)(1) and HEIGHT IS 1 WHICH GIVES 1/6 omggg you went through all that integration you brave soul

Comment: Any tips on the other part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it $99\%$ done.

You already figured out the bounds of the region when you computed $1 \,dz\,dy\,dx$ for the volume.

Now replace $1$ with $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(1+x+y+z)^3}$.

To evaluate can be trickier. Consider $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx$ which turns into $\ln(1+x)$ which when evaluated from $0$ to $1$ becomes $\ln(2)$.

Now consider $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x}\frac{1}{(1+x+y)^2}\,dy\,dx$.

When integrating with respect to $y$, we don't care what $x$ is.

We get $\displaystyle  \int_0^1 -\frac{1}{1+x+y}\biggr |_0^{1-x}\,dx$.

This gives us$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)\,dx=\ln(2)-\frac{1}{2}$.

Now use a similar argument for the case with $3$ variables.

Comment: Nothing complicated here. Just take it slow and steady.

Comment: Should be dz dy dx

Comment: oh sorry, let me edit. @BarryChau

Answer (score 0):

$\int_K\frac{d(x,y,z)}{(1+x+y+z)^3}=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}\frac{1}{(1+x+y+z)^3}\mathop{dz}\mathop{dy}\mathop{dx}$